# Evaluate the limit $\lim_{n\to \infty }\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n} \cdot \lfloor \sqrt {\frac{4i}{n}} \rfloor$

Tags: calculus, limits, riemann-integration, ceiling-and-floor-functions, riemann-sum

I solved the problem using the Riemann integral. However, my answer did not match with the result given in the book. My answer was $\frac{3}{4}$ and the answer given in the book was just 3.

Help me understand where I went wrong. My solution

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n}\cdot \lfloor \sqrt{\frac{4i}{n}}\rfloor 
=\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n} \cdot \lfloor 2\sqrt{\frac{i}{n}}\rfloor=$$
$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n}\cdot \lfloor2\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}}\rfloor+\frac{1}{n}\cdot \lfloor2\sqrt{\frac{2}{n}}\rfloor+\ldots +\frac{1}{n}\cdot \lfloor2\sqrt{\frac{n}{n}}\rfloor\right)$$

Clearly, the given expression is a Riemann sum of the function $\lfloor2\sqrt{x}\rfloor$ on the interval $[0,1]$.

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n}\cdot \lfloor \sqrt{\frac{4i}{n}}\rfloor =$$

$$=\int_0^1 \lfloor2\sqrt{x}\rfloor dx=\int_0^{\frac14} \lfloor2\sqrt{x}\rfloor dx+\int_{\frac14}^1 \lfloor2\sqrt{x}\rfloor dx=0+1\cdot\left(1-\frac14\right)=\frac34$$

Comment: If you've typed the problem in correctly, I don't see how you've done anything wrong. Maybe the book's solution is in error. Note that the result of the floor is mostly $0$ and $1$, with one $2$, so the total result, which is the average of those values, obviously cannot be $3$.

Comment: Gotcha. Thank you very much mate.

Comment: [Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34121/42969). Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. – For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @Teufel I've typed the image as suggested by MartinR. Take a look to it in order to proceed in the same way for the next question. Bye

Comment: Thank you very much for doing so.

Answer (score 8):

Your solution seems fine, to check we can also solve it in a direct way for $n=4N$

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n}\cdot\lfloor\sqrt{\frac{4i}{n}}\rfloor=\sum_{i=1}^{4N} \frac{1}{4N}\cdot\lfloor\sqrt{\frac{i}{N}}\rfloor=$$

$$=\sum_{i=1}^{N-1} \frac{1}{4N}\cdot0+\sum_{i=N}^{4N-1} \frac{1}{4N}\cdot 1+\frac1{2N}=\frac{3}{4}+\frac1{2N} \to \frac34$$

Answer (score 1):

Distinguish the three cases I < n/4, n/4 <= I < n, and I = n, and the result is trivial. This has nothing to do with any integral or Riemann sum.

The square root is 0 <= root < 1 if I < n/4, 1 <= root < 2 if n/4 <= I < n, and 2 if I = n. Rounded down to an integer it is 1 for n/4 <= I < n and 2 if I = n.

The sum therefore is (n - floor(n/4)) / n + 2/n, which is 3/4 + 5/4n <= sun <= 3/4 + 2/n, with limit 3/4.